# Invalid location of <th> tag

Tags: html

Here is the html for a simple jsp page, all the `<th>` tags are invalid location. I am following a guide of the same type of project I am trying to do and this is how the guide is too..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Doctors</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Doctor List</h1>
    <h3><a href="newDoctor">New Doctor</a></h3>
    <table border="1">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Medical Degree</th>
        <th>Education</th>
        <th>Action</th>


        <c:forEach var="doctor" items="${doctors}">
        <tr>
            <td>${doctor.id}</td>
            <td>${doctor.lastName}, ${doctor.firstName}</td>
            <td>${doctor.email}</td>
            <td>${doctor.degree}</td>
            <td>${doctor.education}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="editDoctor?id=${doctor.id}">Edit</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="deleteDoctor?id=${doctor.id}">Delete</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        </c:forEach>             
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Thanks for the quick answers

Comment: They still need to be inside a `tr` element.

Comment: I still don't get the downvote though. SO trolls these days...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `<tr>` tag and place all `<th>` in between that.

Like This:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Doctors</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Doctor List</h1>
    <h3><a href="newDoctor">New Doctor</a></h3>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
           <th>Id</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Medical Degree</th>
           <th>Education</th>
           <th>Action</th>
        </tr>    

        <c:forEach var="doctor" items="${doctors}">
        <tr>
            <td>${doctor.id}</td>
            <td>${doctor.lastName}, ${doctor.firstName}</td>
            <td>${doctor.email}</td>
            <td>${doctor.degree}</td>
            <td>${doctor.education}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="editDoctor?id=${doctor.id}">Edit</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="deleteDoctor?id=${doctor.id}">Delete</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        </c:forEach>             
    </table>
</div>
```

I hope this will solve this issue.

Comment: This solves the similar issue I faced too. I would like to know why this fix? Is this because the previous structure conforms to <= HTML4 and the new standard is HTML5?

Answer (score 2):

looks like you just need some table rows, but lets add `tbody` and `thead` for safe measure:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Medical Degree</th>
        <th>Education</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="doctor" items="${doctors}">
            <tr>
                <td>${doctor.id}</td>
                <td>${doctor.lastName}, ${doctor.firstName}</td>
                <td>${doctor.email}</td>
                <td>${doctor.degree}</td>
                <td>${doctor.education}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="editDoctor?id=${doctor.id}">Edit</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="deleteDoctor?id=${doctor.id}">Delete</a>;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```